# Modifying range when calculating definite integrals using variable change

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

When calculating a definite integral using variable change, like so,
$$
\int_a^b \frac{x}{x^2+1} \,dx
$$
$$
u:=x^2+1, \\ du= 2x \, dx
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_c^d \frac{1}{u}du\,
$$
are $c = d$ and $d = b$, or are $c = u(d)$ and $d = u(a)$?
For example, if $a = 0$, will $c = u(1) = 1$?

Comment: Since $u = x^2 + 1$, we have $c = a^2 + 1, d = b^2 + 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing a substitution, you will need to also change your limits of integration.  For example, if you let $a=1$ and $b=3$, then you need to plug into $u$.  Since you let $u=x^2+1,$ then we have
$$u=a^2+1=1^2+1=2$$ and $$u=b^2+1=3^2+1=10$$ so your integral becomes $$\frac12\int_2^{10}\frac{1}{u}\ du=\frac12\ln(u)\biggr\rvert^{10}_2=\frac{\ln(10)-\ln(2)}{2}$$

Similarly, if we just substitute back and not change limits of integration (with our original example with $a=1$ and $b=3$) we have
$$\frac12\int_1^3\frac{1}{u}\ du=\frac12\ln(u)\biggr\rvert_1^3=\frac12\ln(x^2+1)\biggr\rvert_1^3=\frac{\ln(10)-\ln(2)}{2}$$ and the two solutions are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your second answer is the right one.

Sometimes, however, we do a substitution in the other direction, and things are a little more subtle. In the "forward:" direction that you're using, finding the $u$-limits from the $x$-limits is relatively easy. But consider a case like this

$$
\int_0^\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{1 - x^2}}
$$
where we might do the substitution 
$x = \sin u$, so that $dx = \cos u ~ du$. The integral then becomes
$$
\int_p^q \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 u }} \cos u ~ du
$$
but what are the limits $p$ and $q$? Well, $p$ is the number such that $\sin(p) = 0$ and $q$ is the number such that $\sin(q) = \frac{1}{2}$. So that means that you need to solve an inverse problem. Usually that's not hard, but sometimes it's a waste of time...what if your final answer to such a problem ended up involving only $\sin u$, but not $u$? Then you could replace all the $\sin u$ occurrences with $x$s and be fine. So sometimes I'll write an intermediate integral of this kind in the form
$$
\int_{x = 0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \sin^2 u }} \cos u ~ du
$$
explicitly noting that the limits of integration are limits for the variable $x$ instead of $u$.

Answer (score 0):

In the writing $I=\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)dx$ think the variable "$x$" run over the interval $[a,b]$. 
If you perform a change of variable and that the new "x" is "$y$" then in the new expression of the integral $I=\displaystyle \int_{a'}^{b'} g(y)dy$

the new variable "$y$" run over the interval $[a',b']$.

This is what you have to remember, to know what are $a',b'$ after a change of variable.